# How to swipe to delete Core Data TableViewCell (with row action) in another ViewController in Swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift2, xcode7

To start off I just want to say I am new to iOS Programming and this is my first app so I apologize if I use incorrect terminology or what not.

My app is set up so that I can add an event using Core Data and then 2 tableViews will update with information from that Event. The first tableView I have it configured so that I can swipe to delete the cell and the information from core data.

Swipe to Delete Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Enables swipe to delete for cells

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        moc.deleteObject(events[indexPath.row])
        appDelegate.saveContext()

        events.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In the other tableView however I have a UITableViewRowAction Edit button set up so that when clicked it will take the user to a EditViewController where they can edit the cell.

UITableViewRowAction Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit    ") { (action , indexPath ) -> Void in
        self.editing = false

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("edit", sender: self)

        print("Edit button pressed")
    }

    return [editAction]

}
```

I want a button in this EditViewController to delete the cell and the Core Data information of the cell clicked like I did in the first tableView. In the EditViewController I tried using similar code to the first tableView...

```
var events = [Events]()

@IBAction func deleteButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    moc.deleteObject(events[indexPath.row])
    appDelegate.saveContext()

    events.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

But this does not work because I cannot access the indexPath of the cell that I clicked on. Is there anyway that when I click the UITableViewRowAction Edit Button that I can record the indexPath of the cell and use that information in the EditViewController?

Comment: use tag property in your deleteButton and set indexpath.row into it, or create s subclass of UIButton and define the indexpath property in it

Comment: How would I define the indexPath of the cell that was clicked if i was creating a subclass of UIButton. Im not really sure how this would work could you give an example?

Comment: Can you confirm: is the `deleteButton` code in the (second) table view controller, or in the edit view controller that your edit action segues to?

Comment: It is in the edit View Controller

Comment: Please can you show the `prepareForSegue` code?

Comment: I did not use prepareForSegue... I just set a segue from the tableView2Controller to the editViewController and named it "edit" then called self.performSegueWithIdentifier("edit", sender: self) when the edit button is clicked

Comment: So how do you tell your EditViewController which Event to edit?  Or is that the point of your question?

Comment: Yes that is the point, sorry for the confusion. I want the EditViewController to be able to change information from the event I clicked on and the first thing I was trying to do was to delete the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one is to pass the relevant Event to the EditViewController.  First, amend your edit action closure to get the relevant Event and pass it in the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: " Edit    ") { (action , indexPath ) -> Void in
        self.editing = false
        let eventToPass = events[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("edit", sender: eventToPass)

        print("Edit button pressed")
    }
    return [editAction]    
}
```

Then implement `prepareForSegue`, which is called after you trigger the segue, but before the segue actually occurs.  It's the place to pass information from the first view controller to the segue's destination view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "edit" {
        let editVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditViewController
        editVC.eventToEdit = sender as! Events
    }
}
```

You will need to add an `eventToEdit` property to your `EditViewController`:

```
var eventToEdit : Events?
```

You should then be able to use this property to access the various attributes of the object, and your `deleteButton` code can just delete this object:

```
@IBAction func deleteButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    moc.deleteObject(eventToEdit)
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

That should delete the object successfully, but your table view controller will be blissfully unaware.

Step two is to ensure that the TVC recognises that the object has been deleted.  There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Add some code to `viewWillAppear` in the table view controller, which reloads the Events data from CoreData and reloads the table view.
2. Replace the `popViewController` with an Unwind Segue.
3. Implement a protocol/delegate which enables the EditViewController to directly tell the TVC that the Event has been edited or deleted.
4. Change your TVC to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, which will observe inserted/updated/deleted Events and automatically update the table view.

I would begin by implementing the first of these, and then experiment with the others when you get more confident.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I ended up using a Unwind Segue which fixed the tableView which worked well.